# Linq get last ID inserted

Tags: c#, linq, insert, multiple-tables

I´m trying to do 2 linq insert queries. The second one needs the last inserted id value from the first query.

How can I get the last_id_inserted (last_fich)?

```
db.CWC_FICHEIROS.Add(new CWC_FICHEIROS
{
    idfiletype = newextID,
    filename = fileName,
    fileurl = fileName,
    fileordem = "AA001",
    filedate = System.DateTime.Now,
    fileact = true
 });
last_fich = db.CWC_FICHEIROS.Max(item => item.id_file);

db.CWC_FILESSUBCONTEUDOS.Add(new CWC_FILESSUBCONTEUDOS
{
     idfile = last_fich,
     idsubconte = cwc_subconteudos.idcont,
     fscact = true
});

db.SaveChanges();
```

Like it is, `last_fich` gives me the id of the first row of `CWC_FICHEIROS`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I return the 'id' field after a LINQ insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113928/can-i-return-the-id-field-after-a-linq-insert)

Comment: Use navigation properties!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding an object directly, create your object first and then insert like:

```
var yourOjbect = new CWC_FICHEIROS
{
    idfiletype = newextID,
    filename = fileName,
    fileurl = fileName,
    fileordem = "AA001",
    filedate = System.DateTime.Now,
    fileact = true
};
db.CWC_FICHEIROS.Add(yourObject);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Later you can access its ID as:

```
Console.WriteLine(yourObject.ID);
```

Do not rely on `db.CWC_FICHEIROS.Max`, there could be multiple inserts in the database at the same time and you could end up with the wrong ID.