# Linq insert statement with return value

Tags: c#, linq

I need to convert the following SQL insert statement to LINQ:

```
Insert into Car (Name)
Output inserted.CarId
Values ('Red Car')
```

This is my code so far :

```
       using (MyContextEntities db = new MyContextEntities())
        {
            db.Entry(car).State = EntityState.Added;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

How can I return the Id of the inserted item ?

Comment: `return car.CarId;` after `db.SaveChanges`

Comment: You can even return the full entity if you want. The Id has been changed once you notify EF anyway.

Answer (score 3):

After SaveChanges, car instance already has generated Id

Also, why do you set state but not add an entity to context?

```
 using (MyContextEntities db = new MyContextEntities())
 {
        db.Cars.Add(car);
        db.SaveChanges();
 }
 return car.Id
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra tip.

Answer (score 2):

EF will set in your car instance:

```
using (MyContextEntities db = new MyContextEntities())
{
     db.Entry(car).State = EntityState.Added;
     db.SaveChanges();
     return car.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After `db.SaveChanges` you can access the id for example

```
car.Id
```

[Can I return the 'id' field after a LINQ insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113928/can-i-return-the-id-field-after-a-linq-insert)