# Getting primary key from database entry creation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, primary-key

When creating a new database entry, how would I get the primary key, in this instance, called `DocumentId` as it is created and store it under another variable.

Here is my code to create the new database entry, the `RevisionId` is showing up as `0` because it cannot find the `DocumentId`, the primary key that is automatically incremented each time a new entry is entered. How do I get the number from the `DocumentId`?

```cs
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    documentUps.RevisionId = documentUps.DocumentId; //PROBLEM HERE SHOWS 0
    documentUps.Username = User.Identity.Name;
    documentUps.Attachment = file.FileName;
    documentUps.creationDate = DateTime.Now;
    documentUps.ActivationDate = DateTime.Now;
    documentUps.RevisionNumber = 0;
    documentUps.Status = StatusChoice.Draft;

    db.DocumentUps.Add(documentUps);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: It depends on how is this achieved in the database. In SQL Server, this is normally through an IDENTITY field. Here's a link on how that can be achieved, but you might need some extra model configuration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113928/can-i-return-the-id-field-after-a-linq-insert. If this link doesn't answer your question, please explain how this is configured in the DB and how it is configured in your model classes

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that answers my question perfectly, I need to find the ID After I saved it to the database. Actually makes sense when I think about it haha, thanks

Comment: Glad you solved it. I'll mark it as a duplicate. In future please at least tag the database. You might want consider improving your google-fu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I return the 'id' field after a LINQ insert?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113928/can-i-return-the-id-field-after-a-linq-insert)

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.